# How to return correct model fields in serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am implementing a search bar that returns the users and the posts.
I am able to return the data but when I clear the search bar I get the error returned:

**AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `SearchUserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
The original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'username'.**

My Models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    avi_pic = models.ImageField(
        max_length=400, null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None
    )
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

My Serializers:

```
class SearchPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'user', 'username', 'cover')

    def get_username(self, post):
        return post.user.username

class SearchUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'username', 'avi_pic')
```

and my Views.py:

```
class SearchView(generics.ListAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if len(queryset) == 0:
            return None
        if isinstance(queryset[0], User):
            return SearchUserSerializer
        elif isinstance(queryset[0], Post):
            return SearchPostSerializer
        else:
            return None

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.query_params.get('q', None)
        if query is not None:
            queryset_users = User.objects.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(username__icontains=query))
            queryset_posts = Post.objects.filter(
                Q(playlist_title__icontains=query))
            results = list(queryset_users) + list(queryset_posts)
            return results
        else:
            return User.objects.none()
```

I've tried many things with zero luck.

Comment: where is ur post Model?

Comment: where is your CreateAPIVIEW or post whatever post method u wrote

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class SearchPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'user', 'username', 'cover')
```

This should do the trick .

You can remove the `get_username` function

You can take a look here for the explanation:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: still getting same error. confused as to why the error says it's from the SearchUserSerializer and why it only happens when i clear the searchbar. It also works fine when i remove 'username' from SearchUserSerializer field